# Assigning arrays to a variable. VBA code not clear

Tags: arrays, vba

Could you please explain to me why the following code works?

```
Sub MyTest()
Dim arrL1(3) As Variant
Dim arrTemp(10) As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, s As String
Dim varTemp As Variant

For i = LBound(arrL1) To UBound(arrL1)
    For j = LBound(arrTemp) To UBound(arrTemp)
        arrTemp(j) = i + j
    Next

    **arrL1(i) = arrTemp**
Next
' 2nd part of the code

**For i = LBound(arrL1) To UBound(arrL1)**
    varTemp = arrL1(i)
    s = "" 
    For j = LBound(varTemp) To UBound(varTemp)      
        s = s & Format(varTemp(j), "@@@")
    Next
    Debug.Print s 
Next

End Sub
```

What is confusing me is the first "starred" line `arrL1(i) = arrTemp`. When I try to assign an array in this way in my project I get an `Object or Application defined error`.

Another confusing line is in the 2nd part, i.e., `varTemp = arrL1(i)`. Do we really need another variable `varTemp`? Can we not get away with just `arrL1(i)`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, did you define `Dim arrL1(3) As Variant` , and did you set it exactly like in the loop ?

Regarding your second question, it is not necessary to have `varTemp = arrL1(i)`
 , your code will work without it (just like in the code below).

```
For i = LBound(arrL1) To UBound(arrL1)
    s = ""
    For j = LBound(arrL1(i)) To UBound(arrL1(i))
        s = s & Format(arrL1(i)(j), "@@@")
    Next

    Debug.Print s
Next
```

Comment: @ Shai Rado: As per first question, I've declared "Dim b As Variant", as I don't know in advance the size of my array. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Lola you use `b` instead of `arrL1(3)` ?

Comment: @ Shai Rado: Sorry, I should've been clearer. The code above comes from a textbook. I struggle however to use it in my own code s.t. assigning an array (a table n x k)  to a variant without having to redim it, didn't lead to an error.

Comment: @Lola , you should open another post, show a screen-shot of your worksheeet, od data range you are tyring to put in this array.

Comment: @ Shai Rado: ok. But you could you please explain me what is going on in this code, considering my first question? arrL1(3) has got 4 entries with dimention 1, and we're assigning a two-dimentional array of size (1*11) to each of its 4 entries?

Comment: @ yes, the loop assignsanother 10 elements per existing array, making it a 2-D array

Comment: @ Shai Rado: would this not lead to smth like "type mismatch" or "out of range" error?

Comment: @Lola why have you taken off the **v** of the mark as answer ?